# How to pre-populate a field in WFFM with campaign information

Tags: wffm

Is it possible to pre-populate a WFFM field with campaign link id?

We have a campaign from Twitter, Facebook, and messenger. In the export excel/report we want to know where that visitor came from (ex. is it from Twitter, Facebook or messenger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom field, render it hidden (`style="display:none"`) and prepopulate it via query string.

When you use the field name to select the query string, you end up with a nice flexible solution.